# How to prevent space for first word in EditText? Can be in xml not code?

Tags: android, android-edittext, space

Can I prevent space for first word in EditText without write a code? If I will write a code for this problem, Can I define in onCreate method?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/aranacak_film"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="ARANACAK FİLM">
</EditText>
```

Comment: do you want to prevent spacing for only first word?

Comment: Yes, @Ashish post answer and it works. Thank you for your interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TextWatcher For your Edittext :

```
aranacak_film.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                //
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(s.toString().equals(" "))
                {
                    aranacak_film.setError("Space is not allowed");
                    aranacak_film.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {    
                //
            }
        });
```